# when something like insert into xxx select xxx in a procedure，how to use django-mssql get the recordset of procedure？

Tags: django, procedure, pymssql

In My website，I use django-mssql to connect sqlserver 2008.In My database ，the table are be divide in groups，like t_inout_master_01，t_inout_master_02，...so in the procedure，I use temp table to select the data，when I use insert into xxx select xxx in my procedure，something error happened in both cursor.callproc and cursor.execute。the error says the the recordset is empty。I search for all day but nothing useful got，and the code in dbapi can't help too，can somebody help me？Thanks。